# Updating App Engine Entity with new property: New property and value are OK in datastore viewer but not in handler

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a old model QTip where I added a new property alink

```
class QTip(db.Model):
       # Old property that existed before
       tip_text = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)

       # Recently added this property and it's giving me trouble
       alink = db.StringProperty()
```

I created a **new** QTip entity and populated the alink property. Something like..

```
my_qtip.tip_text = 'Ranglers of the west'
my_qtip.alink = 'http://www.qtips.com/q/%s' % my_qtip.key()
my_qtip.put()
```

Using the datastore viewer, I manually confirmed that each **new** QTip entity now has a value for the alink property.

When I get a QTip entity and try and print alink. I keep getting None.

```
 logging.error(my_qtip.tip_text)   # logs correct value
 logging.error(my_qtip.alink)      # logs 'None' as in None
```

I receive the same results in dev_appserver.py and in production... I wiped the Datastore, I tried to rename the property, change the property... Nothing.

Does anybody have any insight? This should be so straightforward :/

**EDIT: Solved and embarrassed:**

Flushing memcache solved the problem. Was *Always* pulling a stale result out of memcache

Comment: You will need to show how you retrieve the entities.

Comment: On a single instance of entity X, if the old property logs the correct value and the new property on the same entity X does not log any value and in the datastore viewer I can see that both properties do have values - does it matter how I am retrieving the entity?

I know what your getting at, but I know I have an entity because the old property is logging. If I failed to retrieve an entity - and tried to access it's properties I would get AttributeError.

Comment: Well your asking for help.  Appengine works (I have been developing with it since 2008), so the problem is in your code somewhere.  Maybe you have a simple bug in your code. Trying to guess what is causing your problem is hard. Have you tried retrieving the entity using the remote_api and just your model.  That gets a lot of the stack out of the way.  Then you can isolate the problem within your application.

Comment: I do appreciate your help! I will try using remote_api. I know the bug is in my code.

I just tried using the interactive interpreter on the admin console and when I get the entity, the new value is present. Should I still go ahead and set up remote_api or does the interactive interpreter just prove what the remote_api would have proved.

Thank you @TimHoffman

Comment: @TimHoffman you should downvote moi :( I guess I didn't want to show you how I retrieved the entity because it was a long handler and I was trying to be succinct. I will try to be more open next time..

Comment: interactive console was good enough to prove your model and therefore point to your app higher up.  As you can see from what you finally discovered, debugging is all about breaking down into parts you know work and bit's you don't.  Without code anyone else is going to guessing.  Hence why I asked about how you where getting your entities.

Answer (score 0):

Flushing memcache solved the problem. Was Always pulling a stale result out of memcache.

I was:

- Creating the entity
- putting entity to the datastore
- putting entity in memcache
- In a task - adding the new link property
- In request handler - checking if the entity was in memacache and using the memcached entity (which was stale)

eeek!